# Overloaded Constructor Throwing Redefinition Error

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that requires me to write overloaded constructors for a class (Car) in c++.  I keep getting a redefinition error but cannot pinpoint what's causing it.  I feel that it could possibly have to do with the code being separated out between two separate files (Car.h, Car.cpp) but I'm not sure.

Here is the class in Car.h:

```
class Car {
    public:
        Car(){}; 
        Car(string userMake, string userModel, double userPrice){};
        string getMake();
        string getModel();
        double getPrice();
    
    private:
        string make;
        string model;
        double price;
};
```

Here are the constructors throwing the error in Car.cpp:

```
Car::Car () {
   make = "DeLorean";
   model = "Alpha5";
   price = 145000;
}

Car::Car (string userMake, string userModel, double userPrice) {
   make = userMake;
   model = userModel;
   price = userPrice;
}
```

Here are the compiler errors:

```
Car.cpp:6:1: error: redefinition of ‘Car::Car()’
    6 | Car::Car () {
      | ^~~
In file included from Car.cpp:1:
Car.h:10:9: note: ‘Car::Car()’ previously defined here
   10 |         Car(){};
      |         ^~~
Car.cpp:14:1: error: redefinition of ‘Car::Car(std::string, std::string, double)’
   14 | Car::Car (string initMake, string initModel, double initPrice) {
      | ^~~
In file included from Car.cpp:1:
Car.h:11:9: note: ‘Car::Car(std::string, std::string, double)’ previously defined here
   11 |         Car(string initMake, string initModel, double initPrice){};
      |         ^~~
```

I felt like I've been following the examples given during lectures and textbook activities very closely so I'm lost on how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Remove the `{}` in `Car(){};` from the header. Same for the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Car(){}; 
Car(string userMake, string userModel, double userPrice){};
```

These are defining the constructor bodies, not just declaring their signatures. Since it looks like you want to implement the constructors outside of the class in a `.cpp` file (which is good practice to do), just remove the braces. A prototype doesn't have a function body, even an empty one.

```
Car(); 
Car(string userMake, string userModel, double userPrice);
```